# css and table with rows with two out of three columns vertical - can it be more simpler

Tags: html, css

I want to have a price table like shown in the image. [the image of the wanted layout of table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR4YF.png)
The jsfidle is here. [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/lordanubis/n57jadg9/)
I got basically two targets

- Can it be more simpler? It looks like a overkill here with css.
- I have to keep in mind that the table and the table data will be
  created in excel, and the html with data will be copied over into the
  page.
- I would like to use a basic width of the right column where the price
  element is inside, and the left part atomically adjusted. I can't get
  my mind on that to get that right.

Any suggestions or know about a similar sample?

( the container is in real live a container that places the code on a special absolute place )

```css
    #price-table-container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20;
    top: 70px;
    width: 630px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    .price-table-font {
    font-family: "roboto_slabregular";
    }

    .price-table-category-font {
    font-family: 'poiret_oneregular';
    }

    .priceTable {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    }

    .priceTableCategory {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-kerning: 82;
    font-size: 56px;
    color: goldenrod;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 2px 0px;
    }

    .table {
    position: relative;
    }

    .table-row {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    }

    .table-col-left {
    width: 420px;
    height: 95%;
    float: left;
    }

    .table-col-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 95%;
    }

    .treatmentName {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: goldenrod;
    left: 2px;
    top: 4px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 420px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 29px;
    margin: 0;

    }

    .treatmentDesc {
    font-family: "roboto_slablight";
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #111;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 400px;
    line-height: 21px;
    }

    .treatmentPrice {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333;
    // width: 80%;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 29px;
    left: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <p>This is some text at the very top.</p>
    <div id="price-table-container">
        <p>This is some text above the table.</p>
        <div class="priceTable price-table-font">
            <div class="priceTableCategory price-table-category-font">
                This is a category
            </div>
            <div class="table">
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-col-left">
                        <div class="treatmentName">This is a heading in a div element</div>
                        <div class="treatmentDesc">This is some text in a div element.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-col-right">
                        <div class="treatmentPrice">€ 265,95</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-col-left">
                        <div class="treatmentName">This This is some text in a div element is a heading in a div element</div>
                        <div class="treatmentDesc">This is some text in a div element.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-col-right">
                        <div class="treatmentPrice">€ 245,-</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-col-left">
                        <div class="treatmentName">This is a heading in a div element</div>
                        <div class="treatmentDesc">This This This is some text in a div elementis some text in a div elementis some text in a div element.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-col-right">
                        <div class="treatmentPrice">€ 254,00</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="priceTableCategory price-table-category-font">
                    This is a second category
                </div>
.....
  </div> /* end of table */
</body>
```

Any suggestions how to improve this and to get it more easier to build this from within Excel. I dont look for excel code but simplified a html structure and CSS code. Thank you.

Comment: Well tables always look a little ridiculous in HTML with all the fields you need to put, but perhaps consider converting from `div` tags to `table` tags, with `th tr td` tags. It won't really simplify it, but it'll be easier to read, and Excel might be more willing to make a table out of `table` tags. I'm not so sure about what you're trying to do with Excel though so don't take my word on that.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I came from html table and want to do it in css, like recommended elsewhere. Btw, some element will be adjusted with jquery. Excel is no problem here.

Comment: Well if you're trying to use CSS with only div tags then you're doing fine. It looks just like the image you'd posted. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Can it be more simpler? It looks like a overkill here with so much css. Should I change the structure?
I would like to use a basic width of the right column where the price element is inside, and the left part atomically adjusted.